# Javascript Linked List merge returning undefined

Tags: javascript, linked-list

Trying to merge two sorted list question from LeetCode, keep running into undefined result:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.next = null;
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    var res = new ListNode();
    var curr = res;
    while(l1 !== null && l2 !== null) {
        if(l1.val <= l2.val) {
            // Set current node to l1 if less than or equal
            curr = l1;
            // Move l1's head to next
            l1 = l1.next
        } else {
            // Else same case for l2
            curr = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        // Move current to next
        curr = curr.next
    }

    if (l1 !== null) {
        curr = l1;
    } else if (l2 !== null) {
        curr = l2;
    }

    return res;
};
```

Not sure why res is returning `undefined`. From what I can tell, I'm setting res to be the `head` pointer for the resulting linked list nodes and performing the following logic:

While `L1` or `L2` has not reached its end, compare values.
IF `L1.val` is less than or equal to `L2.val`, set it to the current node, then bump up the pointer for `L1` to the next value.
ELSE do the mirror for `L2`.

Once the current node value is set, bump up the node to the next item (either `L1.next` or `L2.next`, which will be overridden by the next larger value from either of the lists) and repeat.

Once we reach the end of either `L1` or `L2`, set the remaining linked list to the current node, then return the head `res` pointer of the full list.

Not sure where I'm going wrong here with the logic, maybe it's getting a little late haha. Apologies if this has been repeated, appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing `current = res` it updates the reference `current` is holding from `res` to `l1`/`l2`. To avoid this, what you want to do is to set the `next` node of `current` instead of the variable `current`  itself. The following code works -

```
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    var res = new ListNode();
    var curr = res;
    while(l1 !== null && l2 !== null) {
        if(l1.val <= l2.val) {
            // Set current node to l1 if less than or equal
            curr.next = l1;
            // Move l1's head to next
            l1 = l1.next
        } else {
            // Else same case for l2
            curr.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        // Move current to next
        curr = curr.next
    }

    if (l1 !== null) {
        curr.next = l1;
    } else if (l2 !== null) {
        curr.next = l2;
    }

    return res.next;
};
```

Comment: Ah I see, I was overriding curr with `l1/l2` reference, thus losing my handle on `res`. Hmm I see...

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but it looks like you're making a copy of `res` into `curr`. Unless you're doing it by reference, it should treat those separately. Meaning all changes you're making to `curr` are not being reflected on `res`.

Comment: Thought everything this JS was done by reference. Would an Object.assign work here?

Comment: If it was by reference all the way you'd face a lot of issues. However it looks like @shawon hit the nail on the head.